# ReflectionClass or class_exists method?

Tags: php, reflection

Which is the main difference between check if a class exists using ReflectionClass approach instead of class_exists method

I know that with ReflectionClass I got OOP features (exceptions, create new instances from class and so on), the question is what will give me more flexibility in the future?

I will have performance problems using ReflectionClass associated to overhead?

Answer (score 2):

If *all* you want to do is check for existence, use `class_exists`, which also has the feature of being able to autoload classes on demand (see second parameter).

`ReflectionClass` is more expensive, but it also provides functionality not otherwise available. If you need it, well then you need it.

Comment: I'm writing a method to check if all dependencies are installed in the execution environment, therefore the class_exists method will be enough for me.

Maybe the best approach to uses the ReflectionClass would be on dynamic creation class task, ok I think that I understood when I can use each one. Thanks :)